# Deploy Aplicação Laravel 5.2 + Angular2

Tags: php, laravel, deploy, angular

Estou desenvolvendo uma pequena aplicação com o Laravel 5.2 e Angular2. Até o momento esta tudo ok no ambiente de desenvolvimento (pra não contrariar :) ). A minha preocupação é como fazer o *deploy* desta aplicação para um servidor compartilhado - neste caso estarei publicando na KingHost.

Já publiquei projetos utilizando outras tecnologias nesta hospedagem sem maiores problemas.

Mas o projeto atual possui NodeJs e Laravel5.2 e ambas possui uma quantidade enorme de dependências que ***acredito*** que não devam ser todas levadas ao servidor. Esta é o meu primeiro projeto com estas duas tecnologias e *não faço a menor ideia de como publicá-las*.
Flávio

Comment: Servidor compartilhado ou servidor dedicado?

Comment: +1 pela pergunta, por que eu vou tirar proveito das respostas por aqui também :) estou com o mesmo impasse, só que na Locaweb.

Comment: Opsss... verdade, esqueci de informar que o serviço de hospedagem é do tipo "Servidor compartilhado"!

Comment: você tem acesso ao ssh deste projeto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em planos de hospedagens compartilhados, o cliente não costuma ter acesso a instalar novos recursos ou serviços para serem utilizados no servidor. O mais comum é ter apenas a liberdade para configurar os recursos já disponíveis no plano contratado.

Apesar de **Laravel** estar listado entre os frameworks suportados pela KingHost, nem **NodeJs** nem **Angular-2** são listados como *"linguagens suportadas"* ou *"frameworks compatíveis"* (ver [Características técnicas](https://www.kinghost.com.br/hospedagem-de-sites#depoimentos))

*Seria necessário acesso ao painel administrativo da hospedagem para averiguar o que esta disponível para você, entre em contato com o suporte deles.

Dentre os planos dessa hospedagem não sei qual te atenderia melhor. Mas em casos com dependências assim, eu utilizaria um droplet no Digital Ocean, onde eu teria liberdade para configurar o ambiente do jeito que necessito.

Answer (score 0):

Recentemente também me deparei com essa questão.

No *Angular*, fiz a `build` no modo `production` com o comando

```
ng build --prod
```

Os arquivos gerados ficam na pasta `build` na raiz da aplicação *Angular*. Faça upload desses arquivos na pasta `/public_html` do servidor.

No caso do *Laravel*, é necessário fazer algumas mudanças:

- Faça upload de toda a pasta do projeto *Laravel* (menos a pasta `public`) na **raiz** do servidor. Sugiro compactar os arquivos para que a transferência demore menos. Descompacte o projeto e dê um nome à pasta. Ex.: laravel;
- Faça upload da pasta `public` na pasta `/public_html` do servidor. Após isso, renomeei-a para o nome desejado;
- No arquivo `index.php` (que estava na pasta `public` do Laravel), edite as seguintes linhas:

  ```
  require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

  $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
  ```

  para

  ```
  require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

  $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
  ```

  Onde `laravel` é o nome da pasta que foi descompactada na raiz do servidor. Caso você coloque em alguma subpasta, ajuste os caminhos até chegarem na pasta `laravel`.

Acesse `http://seudominio.com.br` para ver a aplicação rodando.

Claro que a estrutura de pastas pode variar de acordo com a estrutura da sua aplicação.